# How to host Power BI on my own Portal(like on premise)

Tags: powerbi

I want to deploy the report on my PC (on-premise), so how can I deploy the report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy and install [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/) to deploy Power BI reports on-premise.